# Store user input in array objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

i am trying to get input from user and want to store it in an array.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool
{
    int i;
    char name[10];
    NSMutableArray *myarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",name);

        [myarray addObject:i];
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [myarray addObject:i]; repalce by [myarray addObject:name];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to insert a non Object in NSMutableArray.

`NSMutableArray` can store objects only,

`char` and `int` are data types of `c` language which are not treated as objects in Objective C.

First you need to convert them into objects then You can insert.

Try with this:

```
 [myarray addObject:@(i)]; or
 [myarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

 for name:

 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",name]
```

Answer (score 0):

A textfield will hold user input. Fetch value from the textfield and add it to the array.

```
arryData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"@&", textFieldinput.text, nil];
```

This will work better.